# how to edit mx-fluity navbar code to make multi-level dropdown menus?

Tags: html, css, blogger

I am not a web designer & I do not understand the CSS code very well.
what to edit in the famous mx-fluity blogger template to produce (multi-level) menu on both PC browser and mobile browser with the same style.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you don't want the menu to switch to a "mobile menu" (drop-down). Or do you want the navigation to be a full-width dropdown all the time?

If you want the navigation to remain as it is on the desktop as long as possible you need to look at the media queries.

Somewhere you'll find:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px)
```

Look for the selectors called: #navinti and #mobilenav

You need to prevent #navinti from being hidden, and the same time disable #mobilenav

They currently look somewhat like:

```
#navinti {
   float: none;
   ...
}

#mobilenav {
   display: block;
   ...
}
```

Set it to:

```
#navinti {
   float: left;
   ...
   ...
}

#mobilenav {
   display: none; /* You might have to add an !important to this */
   ...
}
```

At #navinti erase:

background-color
-moz-box-shadow
-webkit-box-shadow
box-shadow

If your navigation isn't wider than the one on the template, you should get away with this down to 500px (width), from there you can hassle your way to say 460px width padding & margin... Unless your navigation has only 2 or 3 points there's not much of a chance you will get it squeezed onto a mobile screen.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not the point :/
what I'm saying is some thing like that
http://cdn.bloggermint.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/css3.jpg

Comment: for instance : 
when I add another ul list using this code :
[link](http://i.imgur.com/4WaRFEZ.png)
it looks like this : 
[link](http://i.imgur.com/DWdBB7k.png)

I'm just asking how to make it looks normal

Comment: Ok, now I understand. Could you send me a link, so I can take a look at the CSS-setup?

Comment: Ok, this is the current test blog [link](http://editmxfluity.blogspot.com/)
and that's its template [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8RwKqMtOQwmd3pSNWh5OXBlWUk/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Have a look if you find a way to add a class to the ul of your sub-navigation. Then add this to your css: 

#navinti ul.yourclass { left: 170px; }

*This assumes all your submenus have a width of 170px;

Comment: no change :/ , could you send to me your gmail so I can make you Admin in the blog ? then you can edit and see changes easily

Comment: Great ,check your inbox :)

Comment: OK, so you need to add: left: 0px; to your ul.subsub. You then probably want to adjust the height of your submenu. You can du this with: ul.subsub li { height: }